# Do I need to call Random.self_init in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

First of all, I don't care about `seed` in this question.

My question is that whether I should call `Random.self_init` every time I want a fresh start in my function?

```
let shuffle l = 
  Random.self_init ();
  let tagl = List.map (fun x -> (Random.bits (), x)) l in
  List.map (fun x -> snd x) (List.sort compare tagl);;
```

**for example, in the above code, is `Random.self_init ()` necessary or not?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's wasteful of entropy to call it every time you want to shuffle. Better to call it once at the beginning of your program. But you do need to initialize the random generator at some point if you want to get different shuffles for different runs of the program. For some applications, you'd want to initialize with specific values you choose yourself (like if you want to be able to reproduce the results later). For that you can use `Random.init` or `Random.full_init`.

Comment: but can I totally remove that? I mean, don't call at all in my program

Comment: If you don't call at all, the program works fine. But it generates the same random numbers every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
(* Initialize Random so it won't use the default seed *)
let _ = Random.self_init()
```

I would include this line after my type definitions and before my functions in every .ml file where I use random, so that each time I run my program I would get a different random numbers.
And I would think Random.self_init is more preferable compared to Random.init and Random.full_init for most programs, but as Jeffrey Scofield said, if you want to reproduce your results, use them.

Comment: It is not necessary to have that line in every ml files. Just having it once in the main file is enough, but it's not a problem to have it several times.